# Why did King Henry V have Cambridge and Grey’s heads cut off?

Tags: historical-accuracy

In Netflix movie *The King (2019)*, what mistakes have Cambridge and Grey made to have King Henry V have their heads cut off? Wikipedia article on this movie didn't give me clear explanation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_(2019_film)) their crime was that, they lost their faith with the new king and tried to conspire against him.

> The English nobles Cambridge and Grey are approached by French agents hoping to induce them to the French cause. Their trust in the new young king wavers, and they then approach Hal's Chief Justice, William Gascoigne, with their concerns.

Further, Henry V beheaded Cambridge and Grey to prove his power to show what he can do to those who goes against him.

> Gascoigne advises the young king that a show of strength is necessary to unite England, so to prove his competency.....has Cambridge and Grey beheaded.